# Java - swing timer in WHILE, with enable / disable button

Tags: java, swing, timer, do-while

Been searching here for three days, found some answers, but can't understand how to implement the solutions. So, I reverted code to the first version and decided to ask.

My code has two problems, and reading about threads and concurency does not explain how to multi-use swing timer, how to startd and stop timer INSIDE A LOOP, and how to disable button when timer starts and re-enable when stops.

When you click button it will roll die, timer has to do its sequence that number of times and stop, but if the die number is 6 it has to start it again, in

"do{ timer loop }while(die==6);"

In my code button doesn't get disabled. If 6 is rolled, timer immediately goes off without waiting to finish previous moving, and you can click button before everything is done, making JLabel movement even messier.

Could someone, please, show me how to make this work? I have more of these to write and need to see the example, and learn from it.

Please.

Thanks in advance for your understanding.

Here's the code:

```
    import java.awt.EventQueue;
    import java.awt.Toolkit;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import static java.lang.Math.random;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.Timer;

    public class RunPhysics extends JFrame {
        private final int waits = 200;
        private JLabel blackBoard = new JLabel();
        private JLabel label = new JLabel("a=F/m -> O");
        private JButton roll = new JButton("Roll");
        private int labelX = 10;
        private int labelY = 60;
        private int die;
        private Timer timer;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable () {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new RunPhysics();
                }
            });
        }

        public RunPhysics() {
            setSize(1000, 200);
            setTitle("Running Physics");
            setLayout(null);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);
            getContentPane().add(blackBoard);
            blackBoard.setBounds(10, 10, 980, 280);
            blackBoard.add(label);
            blackBoard.add(roll);
            label.setBounds(30, 50, 100, 20);
            roll.setBounds(10, 10, 60, 30);


            roll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent roller) {
                    do {labelX = 10;
                        die = (int)(random()*6+1);
                        roll.setEnabled(false);
        System.out.println(die + " was rolled.");
                        timer = new Timer( waits, new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent mover) {
                                Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                                label.setLocation(labelX, labelY);    
                                if (labelX >= 900) {((Timer)mover.getSource()).stop();}
                                else { labelX+=36; }
                            }
                        });
                        timer.start();
                    } while (die == 6); // “Dice” is the plural form of the singular noun “Die”.
                    roll.setEnabled(true);
        System.out.println("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: `and reading about threads and concurency does not explain how to multi-use swing timer, how to startd and stop timer INSIDE A LOOP` - that is because the Timer `REPLACES` the loop. Get rid of the loop. The Timer will generate an event at the time period you specify.

Comment: Yes, timer is loop to move JLabel step by step. It was replacement for the original FOR loop. Now, how to put it inside another timer that would replace WHILE?

Comment: You don't need the while loop! You stop the Timer when some event happens. Maybe the user clicks a button or type a specific key.

Comment: I AM trying to get rid of DO. Event is if click on button rolls 6, thne timer loop has to go again, and if it is not 6 then the timer loop is not going. See the code.

Comment: So create a frame with two buttons, Start and Stop. The start button will start the Timer. When the Timer fires you simply display the current time. The stop button will then just stop the Timer. Once you understand the basics of starting/stoping the Timer based on a user event, you can apply the knowledge to your real application. This process is how you simplify the problem. Then if you still can't get the code to work you have simple code to post in the forum.

Comment: Timer already stops when finishes moving the JLabel. After that I can click button again, see the roll number and make JLabel move again. Timer will do it and stop again. Question is how to repeat timer without click if the roll number is 6. And how to prevent button to be clicked while it is happening.

Comment: `I AM trying to get rid of DO` - then get rid of it. Don't post code using the looping structure. Once you start a Timer is will keep going until you stop it, so there is no need for a loop. All you need to do is generate a random number. Then you have an if/else statement based on your requirements. Either you keep the Tmier running or you stop the Timer. I don't understand your exact requirement so I can't give an exact solution. All I know is you need to write the code without the loop!

Comment: `And how to prevent button to be clicked while it is happening.` - disable the button. `how to repeat timer without click if the roll number is 6.` -  I don't understand the question. If should be a simple if statement. If the value is "6" then start the Timer. Don't keep creating a new Timer. You create the Timer in the constructor of your class. Then you just start/stop the Timer based on your requirements.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. One click on button rolls the die and timer goes on, finishes and goes off. If the rolled number was 6 then without click die is rolled again and timer goes again, stops and program checks again if it was six. If it was not six, then button is free to click again and repeat process with checking if was 6 or not. Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: I already have "roll.setEnabled(false);" (and true) in the code. I already have timer started and stopped. DO is just checking if the rolled number is 6. If it was the whole ActionPerformed should repeat itself without click. It is not working as it was supposed to. If it was 6 it starts timer together with already started timer and messes with JLabel moving. And it meeses more ifyou click button during that.

Comment: Why do you keep posting comments? You haven't made any changes to your code. Then main problem is your loop. How many times do I have to say "get rid of it"? `already have "roll.setEnabled(false);" (and true) in the code.` - That code does nothing! You set it false and then the next statement you make it true. You should only set it true when you stop the Timer. ` if the rolled number is 6...` - so you need to create a method. This method is invoked when you initially click the button. Then you can also invoke the same method when the value is "6".

Comment: How??? With all this talk I still don't see how. That's why I'm posting comments. Thanks anyway, and good luck. Someone will eventually paste this into editor, run it, and show me what to change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ActionListener for the button is responsible for starting the animation. So all you do is set the properties of your components and then start the animation. So it might look something like:

```
roll.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent roller)
    {
        // disable the roll button
        // set the labelX to its start value
        // set the label location
        // start the timer
    }
});
```

The Timer ActionListener is then responsible for:

1. the original animation
2. determining when to stop the animation
3. restarting animation depending on the roll of the dice

So the code should be defined in the constructor of your class (not in the ActionListener of the button) and might look something like:

```
timer = new Timer( waits, new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent mover)
    {
        // do the basic animation

        // 1. increment the labelX value
        // 2. set the location of the label

        // determine when to stop the animation 

        if (your stop condition is satisfied)
        {
            // stop the timeer
            // enable the roll button

            int die = (int)(random()*6+1);
            System.out.println(die + " was rolled.");

            //  auto restart the animation

            if (die > 4) // make it easier to test auto repeat
            {
                // Reset the component properties and restart the timer.
                // The code here is the same as the code for the roll button
                // that is why I suggested you create a method
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Again the point of this answer to understand the separation of

1. the user starting some kind of processing
2. having the Timer be responsible for its animation and knowing when to stop/restart the animation.

It may not be exactly what you want but should give you the basics for a better structure to implement your exact requirement.

Comment: Thanks. I was experimenting with this and took me time to understand it better. Requires fundamental change in the way of thinking, 20 years old step-by-step structuring is only a burden. Timer loops on its own what we tell it, branches dynamically as we direct it, and loops next tasks as we put them.